# Upgrade to 14.04 Serious errors were found while checking the disk drive for /

Tags: boot, upgrade, wubi

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS from 13.10.
I had installed the earlier version using WUBI.
I am receiving the following error on booting Ubuntu with the latest kernel 3.14

Serious error while checking for the  disk drive for /

The follow up says either to ignore, skip mounting or the manual recovery.
I can boot into Ubuntu 14.04 using the previous kernel version 3.11 in the advanced options specified in the boot options of Ubuntu.
I have run the fsck on the root.disk and it says the disk is clean.

Comment: Have you tried [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)?

Comment: boot-repair doesn't seem to work for Ubuntu 14.04. I tried using the live disk to install but it says that the package was not found.

Comment: Edit /etc/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair-trusty.list (I think its called) and change trusty to saucy, then sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get install boot-repair.

Comment: I would recommend [boot-repair-disk](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/), as it is handy to have around.

Comment: I did the boot repair. It did not help. Still have the same errors with the latest kernel.

Comment: The same problem even when installing ubuntu 14.04 LTS (not upgrade)via wubi. Need a solution

Comment: me too ubuntu 14.04 works with kernel 3.11 but not 3.13 or 3.14

Comment: Same problem here. My system couldn't load /tmp so I started manual recovery. I ran dpkg-reconfigure -a but it said unable to create/open lock file. Read only file system. /tmp also shown as a read-only file system. Donnow what to do.

Comment: Found the solution here:
[link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/453411/ubuntu-14-04-not-booting-after-error-message-temp-could-not-be-mounted)