# Serious errors were found while checking the disk drive for /

Tags: upgrade, disk

Upgraded from 13.10 to 14.04. All seemed to go ok, but following reboot I get this message:

> Serious errors were found while checking the disk drive for /.

If I ignore that one, I get a further message:

> The disk drive for /tmp is not ready yet or not present

And fails to boot. What can I do? Is it possible to do a manual recovery?

Comment: Serious errors should never be ignored. It's possible the drive has failed. 
Obtain a Live DVD, boot from it and see if you can mount the drive.

Comment: Look at this http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2218439

Answer (score 0):

Here is a thread on how to solve the issue it works i tested it.

[Ubuntu 14.04 not booting after error message. /tmp could not be mounted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453411/ubuntu-14-04-not-booting-after-error-message-temp-could-not-be-mounted)

Comment: What you mean is, this question is a duplicate of that one. Flag the question and / or post the link as a comment, but do not encourage this behavior (posting duplicates instead of searching the site) by providing an answer.