# How to change lines at the Grub2 boot entry

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I have installed the new version of Ubuntu, 14.04, with Windows XP. At first, by booting I had the error message:

```
Serious errors were found while checking the disk drive for /.
```

I found a solution at ["Ubuntu 14.04 not booting after error message. /temp could not be mounted"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453411/ubuntu-14-04-not-booting-after-error-message-temp-could-not-be-mounted). But I could only change the GRUB2 boot entry. When I boot with Ubuntu:

- Start the terminal and type `sudo vi /etc/grub.d/10_lupin` and enter.
- I find the line :

  ```
  linux   ${rel_dirname}/${basename} root=${LINUX_HOST_DEVICE} loop=${loop_file_relative} ro ${args}  and change it to  : linux   ${rel_dirname}/${basename} root=${LINUX_HOST_DEVICE} loop=${loop_file_relative} rw ${args}
  ```

But after that, I don't know what to do?

Answer (score 0):

I've found this post which can be helpful in this case:

http://www.howtoforge.com/faq/12_15_en.html

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Although this may help to solve the answer, you may want to expand on this, or put this into comments when you have enough reputation.