# “Errors were found while checking the disk for /” , no /tmp mounting error

Tags: grub2, 14.04, mount, hard-drive

I've been recently experiencing following error during every time I boot into ubuntu:

> Errors were found while checking the disk drive for /.

However everything seems to work file once I choose to ignore the message, by pressing It . Note that it does not say "Serious errors..." and doesn't report an error , such as "/tmp could not be mounted" as described in posts such as

[Ubuntu 14.04 not booting after error message. /tmp could not be mounted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453411/ubuntu-14-04-not-booting-after-error-message-tmp-could-not-be-mounted)

Or [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2218439.)

I've been using 14.04 since May/2014 alongside Windows 7 without any problem till recently this started. 
`gnome-disk-utility` Smart Data & Self test doesn't show any error.
I'm worried about health of my Hard Disc as it holds some important chunk of data.
It would be great if someone could help me out on this,
Thanks in advance...

Comment: You would expect that message, "Errors were found while checking the disk drive for ..." should be accompanied by the actual error messages.  Did they come before this message?  Or can they be found in a log?

Comment: @neon_overload: No message before "Errors were found ..." is flashed. I tried to check logs at boot.log and dmesg but I'm not sure how to look for errors in these logs, it would be helpful if you could tell me how to.

Comment: Boot a live usb, make sure all your partitions are unmounted, and run `fsck -y /dev/sda`, update your question with any error messages

Comment: @bodhi.zazen : Thank you very much. Ran fsck by booting live usb, error were detected and fixed as well. The error message wasn't displayed in the boot that followed !! Thanks again !!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boot a live usb, make sure all your partitions are unmounted, and run:

```
sudo fsck -y /dev/sda
```

change "sda" to your hard drive.

This command will try to fix the problem(s). if it does not work, update your question with any error messages