# Ubuntu 14.04 : "serious errors were found while checking the disk for / " and after that Linux hangs very often

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, windows-8

I have been using dual boot alongside Windows 8.1 from 1 year. Very recently the windows shut down unexpectedly, and then started showing "Trying to repair Windows".
I knew it would harm Ubuntu file system, so i immediately powered off laptop. 
Next time when I booted it up, it shown that

> **"serious errors were found while checking the disk for /"**

Then somehow, Ubuntu was able to fix it (I don't know how), and it booted up next time. But from then till today it works very very slowly ! All the programs and applications, even the Terminal opens after 2-5 minutes of clicking.
I have gone through 
[this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58302/i-get-a-serious-errors-while-checking-the-disk-drives-for-boot-error-while-bo) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/491678/errors-were-found-while-checking-the-disk-for-no-tmp-mounting-error) link, but they didn't help! 
Is there some other way to get past this other than reinstalling ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking through all of the existing solutions, The problem was none related to software, instead, it was a Hardware problem.
The solution was simply to replace the hard disk.