# Upgrade WUBI installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS to 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, wubi

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS into Windows XP using Wubi.exe.  *Update Manager* tells me an upgrade to 14.04 is available, and the *Manager* has an "Upgrade" button.  If I click that, will it upgrade my wubi-installed Ubuntu in Windows and leave Windows intact, or will it install the upgrade on top of Windows, thereby, eliminating Windows?  I want to keep things just as they are except have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS instead of 12.04 LTS.  Would it be better for me to uninstall 12.04 and do a fresh install using Wubi.exe (14.04)?

Comment: Not sure if this has been fixed: http://askubuntu.com/questions/453411/ubuntu-14-04-not-booting-after-error-message-tmp-could-not-be-mounted You'll need to hold down the `Shift` key when booting after the upgrade to edit the grub menu entry.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/449486/windows-installer-for-ubuntu-14-04-lts-onwards

Answer (score 0):

The upgrade won't touch Windows. However, it will need plenty of free space - upwards of 3GB. So if you have the free space, go on ahead.

Answer (score 0):

The upgrade does run an update-grub but it does not replace the main bootloader and maintains that configuration and such, though my recommendation is that you actually use `sudo do-release-upgrade` as I've had problems with the gui crashing and leaving the update running but not completely.

Comment: wait...what? why downvote? :(

Answer (score 0):

Do not upgrade your Ubuntu release if you installed it with WUBI. WUBI is only mean for ***testing*** Ubuntu on your PC. If you wish to fully use Ubuntu and make future upgrades in the future then please make a real install, make a partition destined only for ubuntu.

Repeat, do not atempt to upgrade your ubuntu release if you installed it with WUBI. WUBI is also no longer maintained.

Comment: THe warning is all well and good, but does upgrading cause any harm?

Comment: @muru yes,wubi is mean just for testing ubuntu.

Comment: The question is: Is any harm done? What things are "meant" for doesn't really matter, it's how people use them that matters. People do use Wubi for normal usage, and people have upgraded wubi Ubuntu without problems. So your statement is pure fear mongering.

Comment: If it had been installed with wubi it is the same as a normal dual boot and doesn't actually have any difference. I read up on it and although it was in some ways meant for testing the main reason for it was for someone to not have to deal with changing boot devices and messing with fully booting a livecd so people could feel safe installing from a familiar environment. The only reason it was discontinued was because of the uefi business and windows 8 compatibility issues

Comment: please do not draw any line between originally wubi installations and those used to dual boot normally