# Downloaded ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-i386 from Ubuntu site but not able to unstall

Tags: 14.04, wubi

I had downloaded the latest Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop, and later double clicked on "wubi.exe" from the WINRAR Zip file that was earlier downloaded. The next thing that happened was that another download began (which I had directed to be downloaded into the Partition where I wanted to install the Software. Mine is Windows XP, with Four partitioned Disk each 40 GB. The second download mentioned took about four hrs and a half (nearly 2.6 GB) and when the end point neared an error occurred and I could not do anything further. I note that all the files are installed somewhere in my Computer. But I am not able to get at te destination. How do I proceed? Please Help

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I install Ubuntu without removing Windows?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1366/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-without-removing-windows); please be aware that Wubi is deprecated and unsupported since quite a while.

Comment: My question is not this

Comment: What was the error message at the end of the download then?

Comment: There was a mention of a temp file log. I did not have time to take down. I am not an advanced user, although I do often install new software self. Would there be a log of such files? If so ... may be I could look at them. pl guide

Comment: I recommend that you try to install again and this time save the error message and referred log file. Then you can [edit] your question to add the additional info.

Comment: Save yourself the trouble. The log file is in the `%TEMP%` directory and called `wubi-nn.nn-revnnn.log`. Also `wubi.exe` wasn't released with 14.04.1 so it won't allow you to install it. But it also fails 14.04 because the online md5sums have changed. I wouldn't recommend Wubi

Comment: Ok... thank you ... How do I upload a text file to you (c:\docume~1\hariha~1\locals~1\temp\wubi-14.04-rev286.log) so that you could look at it and guide me?

Comment: Use a paste service like http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/ and [edit] your question to append the link.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to install Ubuntu 14.04.1 using Wubi.

1. Download the ISO and wubi.exe from http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04.1
2. Place the two items in the same directory with no other ISOs (is the best)
3. Disconnect from the internet (or else wubi will reject the ISO)
4. Run Wubi and install normally, but **don't restart your computer**.
5. Reconnect to the internet and reboot your computer (otherwise your wifi card may remain disabled)

You have to do this offline because otherwise it downloads the wrong `md5sum` and fails the ISO and then downloads another. I didn't bother going through the process to see why that fails.

Once you've rebooted and the installation is completed, it won't boot though due to another weirdness since 14.04. You have to edit the grub entry first. Wubi suppresses the display of the Grub menu, so hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key after selecting Ubuntu and then follow the instructions here: [Ubuntu 14.04 not booting after error message. /tmp could not be mounted](https://askubuntu.com/a/454943/14916)

For this (and other issues) I recommend not using Wubi. But if you want to, that's how.

P.S. Because you're skipping the `md5sum` check, there is a risk that your ISO download is corrupted or incomplete and this can lead to failures. Depending on the reliability of your internet connection you may wish to manually verify the `md5sum` yourself.