# Ubuntu 14.04 Wubi Installation: root.disk is write-protected cant be mount

Tags: mount, wubi

I've installed Ubuntu through Wubi. As the Wubi is not working well with 14.04 the disk / is mounting as read only. So I rebooted and gone through recovery mode and choosed root terminal. I tried to remount using `mount -o remount,rw /` but it says it cant be mounted and the root.disk is write protected. What to do now?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 14.04 not booting after error message. /tmp could not be mounted](http://askubuntu.com/questions/453411/ubuntu-14-04-not-booting-after-error-message-tmp-could-not-be-mounted)

Comment: Don't use wubi any more: it's deprecated...

Answer (score -1):

Wubi worked too well so they stopped support for it and are forcing regular install which has never worked for me.  At least not without erasing my windows partition.