# Is installing with Wubi on my computer safe?

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, windows, wubi

I want to dual boot 14.04 Trusty with my computer running Windows 10 Technical Preview. My computer was originally shipped with Windows 7, but my hard drive failed so I purchased a new one and installed Win 10. I'm guessing i'd be ok because my computer was originally Windows 7, but I wanted to check first. Can I use Wubi to install Ubuntu on my machine?

EDIT: I checked my BIOS mode, I have Legacy boot and not UEFI.

Comment: Alone the fact that you're running a prerelease OS only on your (I guess main) computer suggests that safety isn't a priority to you...

Comment: No, this isn't my main computer. I guess I made it sound like it was in the question, though...

Comment: You can, I would say. As soon as it booted, it should not be much slower than a normally installed Ubuntu, except for disk access maybe. However, if your Win10 goes mad and damages the Ubuntu installation (WUBI installs Ubuntu as a Windows program! It is bootable, but located on the windows partition and deinstallable from its system control) you might wish you better installed it properly. I'd better be careful with WUBI on prerelease Windows versions, but that's my opinion.

Comment: have a look at http://askubuntu.com/a/221930/354350

Comment: Wubi is (effectively) no longer supported.

Comment: I'd recommend a normal dual boot. If you do use Wubi for 14.04, then it won't boot without a [workaround](http://askubuntu.com/q/453411/14916)

Answer (score 6):

Considering that you are running Windows 10 and the last version of Wubi said that it does not support anything higher than 7, I would say that it could be dangerous to install Ubuntu this way. 
But hey, as long as you back everything up on your Windows partition and are willing to reinstall it all from scratch, I'd say give it a try!

Sometimes the best way to learn is to learn by experimentation.