# Ubuntu first login

Tags: 14.04, gnome, wubi, home-directory

I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my windows using wubi installer. It installed successfully and when I first login, there's only the terminal is available. I've logged in by entering my user name and there waits an error. The home directory itself isn't created for me. And the GNOME isn't enabled. there was an error related to mkdir. please somebody help me sort this out.

Comment: Wubi is deprecated. I would recommend you to use a VM (i.e. VirtualBox) or install on a separated partition/disk

Comment: Yeah, don't use wubi anymore.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 14.04 not booting after error message. /tmp could not be mounted](http://askubuntu.com/questions/453411/ubuntu-14-04-not-booting-after-error-message-tmp-could-not-be-mounted)

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like a messed up installation that is hard to fix. Easier would be to install again with a live-usb/cd install.
You can use a tool like [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) to create a bootable USB stick or burn the image to a CD. wubi doesn't work very well in some cases so starting the live system and install will be much easier.

Comment: See,I want to use the Ubuntu in that way. Consuming less memory in HDD.So, Install it on a separate partition or VMWare are not an option, as I have low memory,like 22GB on C: ...