# Password denied after installing from Wubi

Tags: password, encryption

I am trying to install a dual boot with windows 7. Old wubi does the job but i have password problems. It doesn't accept my password after setup. I chose password from wubi . I had to install twice to see if i did something wrong. It just doesn't accept. I can only login as a guest and it doesn't give many permission.

One thing is suspicious. I have access the settings of ubuntu from windows, so i can see user name and encrypted password. Even i choose the same password on two install encrypted passwords are different.

I know it is EOL product but what is going on with Wubi? 
How do i install this with something similar to wubi?

Comment: Please just don't use WUBI, if you don't want to do a real install then consider using a virtual machine.

Comment: I want to do a real install but i can't manage my disk. I have free space but  to install it should be unallocated. I couldn't manage that.

Comment: Many Windows 7 systems use all 4 primary partitions. Or some users try to add partitions using Windows and Windows converts to its own proprietary dynamic partitions which will not work with Linux. Post this: `sudo parted -l`

Comment: Maybe, your Wubi version is **too** old. Did it download a broken version of 13.04? https://bugs.launchpad.net/wubi/+bug/1152708

Comment: yes, it installed 13.04, probably broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:
Old Wubi versions have bugs but i have found a solution from a forum post at ubuntuforums.org i can't find the same post but i have the links to patched files.
This files are working. I tried the wubi from this link and worked.

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6uqomp8l1frcd1y/AAAhSCimTaYE-94egbmc1X_na?dl=0

Thanks to hakuna_matata

Comment: Even this is correct answer, i don't recommend doing this. I get a lot of error and problems. Please do a clean boot install by using a USB.

Comment: What  kind of errors and problems do you mean? I also don't recommend Wubi but **these** Wubi versions are definitely not the reason.

Comment: It is not stable. I don't remember the errors exacly but it was really annoying. After 2 days, I made a clean install. I am not very experienced on the issue.

Comment: If I speak from my own experience it is stable. I have always a back-up of my root.disk but I have never needed it. An install of 15.04 is about 6 months old and I installed 15.10, too. My issue was only to install it and these Wubi versions solved the issue. But I think that these versions don't solve general Wubi drawbacks. e.g.: the file system is less stable especially if you have freezes and don't use [Magic_SysRq_Key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key)

Answer (score 1):

Your password issue is a problem of outdated Wubi versions. If it is your wish to use an old Wubi version that works without password issue, try lastest version for 12.04: http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/wubi.exe

In your case (Windows is not in UEFI mode) it should work.

Comment: You know the error but solution. Thanks anyways. I am writing solution here.

Comment: IMHO Wubi version for 12.04.5 should be the easiest official solution. Of course, you can also use Wubi version for 14.04 (http://releases.ubuntu.com/trusty/wubi.exe) but there are other issues like http://askubuntu.com/questions/453411/ubuntu-14-04-not-booting-after-error-message-tmp-could-not-be-mounted 

It is also possible to use unofficial Wubi versions linked in some workarounds of hakuna_matata (I read http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2251986&p=13162861#post13162861) but unfortunately, these versions are still unoffical. I thought in your case it was not necessary to use them.