# Better Way To Install Ubuntu 15.10 Without Making Partitions

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, wubi, 15.10

This is my first post on askubuntu. So, if i break any rules, then please do tell me.

I am using Windows 10, on a 4gb ram,64 bit environment.
Previously when I used to install Ubuntu then I used to install it with wubi. So, I didn't have to make extra partitions or so. But,now as I came to know from some of the post on this forum that wubi is no longer available for installation of ubuntu. Is it even possible to install ubuntu 15.10 in the same way as wubi did, but manually, or any other software.

While using wubi, if ubuntu had problems, I could just simply uninstall ubuntu from the control panel. And nothing else. So, I don't want to make extra partition to install ubuntu.

Steps Tried:
I installed ubuntu 13.10 using wubi. And then upgraded the ubuntu to latest version. After upgrade when it restarted, there was mounting problem,So again had to uninstall. Is there way to solve this mounting.

Any Help/Explaination would be nice.

Comment: Wubi has been pulled by Canonical, but there are community supported version [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6uqomp8l1frcd1y/AAAhSCimTaYE-94egbmc1X_na)

Comment: Unetbootin have a feature to install ubuntu like wubi (you can uninstall later from control panel) but did not save anything and after reboot you have a fresh Ubuntu! http://sourceforge.net/p/unetbootin/wiki/installmodes/#hard-disk-install-mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there way to solve this mounting.

See answers of [Ubuntu 14.04 not booting after error message. /tmp could not be mounted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453411/ubuntu-14-04-not-booting-after-error-message-tmp-could-not-be-mounted)

> Is it even possible to install ubuntu 15.10 in the same way as wubi did, but manually, or any other software.

I installed 15.10 with Wubi without any problems. There is no official Wubi solution (besides to remove it from isos) but community supported versions still exist. See solutions of other Wubi users like [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/655036/386067).

Answer (score 1):

If you're not doing anything terribly resource intensive and just want to play around with it (which is implied by the fact you're wanting to use Wubi instead of giving it its own partition outside of Windows), you could just install Ubuntu in a virtual machine.

I use Oracle VirtualBox (www.virtualbox.org) to create and manage virtual machines, but there are others out there that are free.

If your concern is for your Windows partition, you can always just use GParted Live to resize your Windows partition back to full if you install Ubuntu and change your mind about it later.

You can find a little more information about the state of Wubi at this askubuntu page: [Windows installer for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS onwards](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449486/windows-installer-for-ubuntu-14-04-lts-onwards)

Answer (score 0):

According to [Rinzwind's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/449526/295286) on [Windows installer for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS onwards](https://askubuntu.com/q/449486/295286) question , WUBI is still supported but [it's not recommended to use](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/04/wubi-advice).

As far as Ubuntu installation is concerned ( or really any OS ) a hard drive has to be partitioned. That isn't exclusive to WUBI - any installer does that - Windows, Mac , or Linux. New Ubuntu installer does the same thing. An operating system needs to live somewhere on the hard drive.

If you don't want to partition a hard drive, there's three options: have another hard-drive with Ubuntu, install Ubuntu as the only OS on the drive (which is still partitions the drive to only have two partitions - Ubuntu and swap ), and use virtual machine. The last one is the best - I have 4 different virtual machines in VirtualBox. If anything goes wrong - just delete the virtual machine and start over.

Follow this guide on how to install Ubuntu in VirtualBox:

[How to install Ubuntu on VirtualBox?](https://askubuntu.com/q/142549/295286)

Comment: wubi does make partititions,but it were virtual partitions which wubi had to take care not me.

Comment: @KishanKumar true, but essentially it still took up a chunk of your hard drive. It's impossible to have OS and not take up a some space on hard drive. Seriously, look into VirtualBox - it's the best alternative. Or qemu. Or VMWare, or KVM . . . Same idea

Comment: My problem is that I have only 4gb of rams. And when I want to use ubuntu then give it the whole chunk of it. And through virtualbox, I will be able to give only some part of it. As windows will also be running by side.

Comment: Is your computer a laptop or desktop ?

Comment: It is  a laptop.

Comment: @KishanKumar hmm, so for that . . . .probably running Ubuntu off an external USB  hard drive is better option, but then again it might be slow, because USB transfer rate.  It really depends on your priorities - if you want to give Ubuntu control of resources either partition or run off external drive; if you don't want to partition - use virtual machine. I personally have Windows 7 and Ubuntu 15.04 living happiliy on a partitioned disk

Comment: I am thinking to make a partition now, for ubuntu. As wubi is no longer recommended. BTW, can you say anything on the mounting problem, I had when, I updated the ubuntu 13.10 installed via wubi

Comment: @KishanKumar No idea. Probably after you updated Ubuntu you also needed to make some form of updates in wubi, but i am no expert on that

Comment: Ok. I hope some one else answers that too

Comment: @KishanKumar: See [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/453411/ubuntu-14-04-not-booting-after-error-message-tmp-could-not-be-mounted) for your upgrade issue and [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/655036/386067) if you need a working Wubi for 15.10.

Comment: @ngngYou just answered my whole question. So please submit an detailed answer.

Comment: @KishanKumar: I tried it. I hope my answer is not too Wubi friendly and will be deleted by other users.