# password invalid 12.04 when tryin to log in for the first time, cant get past login screen

Tags: password, password-recovery

i installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my computer, to boot up alongside windows. I did this through Wubi Installer, When i try to log in, it says that my password is not valid. I have reinstalled it a couple times, but i keep getting the same thing.

Comment: What version of Windows?

Comment: i have windows xp home edition

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Password denied after installing from Wubi](http://askubuntu.com/questions/653144/password-denied-after-installing-from-wubi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a question for wubi; I would [report a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/wubi/+bugs) to wubi as this is not an issue with standard installation of Ubuntu ; and can't be duplicated to troubleshoot.