# update-grub failing ubuntu 14.04 (wubi)

Tags: 14.04, grub2, wubi

When I try to run sudo update-grub, I get the following error:

```
    Generating grub configuration file ...  
    /etc/grub.d/10_lupin: 26: /etc/grub.d/10_lupin: data: not found
```

Any ideas what this could mean or how to fix it?
Here is the contents of my 10_lupin file: http://pastebin.com/nDZ9v5sJ

Comment: Where did you get that `10-lupin` file. What is it for?

Comment: @Pilot6 It's from /etc/grub.d/    .      I believe it is part of grub. Other than that, I don’t know much about it.

Comment: I do not have this file. It means that you installed it for some reason. If you do not know what is it for, then just delete it.

Comment: Well these people happen to have it: http://askubuntu.com/questions/453411/ubuntu-14-04-not-booting-after-error-message-tmp-could-not-be-mounted

Comment: Do you have a wubi install?

Comment: @Pilot6 Yes, I do. Forgot to mention that. Sorry.

Comment: Wubi is obsolete. I am afraid, you will not get support for it now.

Comment: Officially wubi is still supported - precise has 3 more years of support, and wubi has not yet been removed from any isos and is present to download for all releases and is present on all released .isos. (12.10, 13.04, 13.10 and 12.04.x point releases) http://askubuntu.com/questions/449486/windows-installer-for-ubuntu-14-04-lts-onwards

Comment: That is true. But not many people use it. It will be hard to get support. That's it.

Comment: And wubi does not support Windows 8 as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your /etc/grub.d/10_lupin contains an error in line 26:

```
data otdir="${prefix}/share"
```

should be

```
datarootdir="${prefix}/share"
```

To restore that file just reinstall package lupin-support

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall lupin-support
```

Comment: If your file /etc/grub.d/10_lupin contains more than one error, it is easier to restore the whole file. I added reinstalling of package lupin-support.

Comment: Thanks so much, my question is part of a wider issue, in which I cannot install or remove packages, because some obsolete kernel is half configured. I have tried everything, so hopefully this should fix it and I should be able to configure the kernel and then remove it.