# Changing disk partition

Tags: boot, partitioning, wubi

I installed my ubuntu and everything is cool, but I have only 11GB of space and it's a little bit not enough. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed from Wubi (I sellected 18GB, 'cause I didn't actually know what instalation size mean) and I want to make it bigger so I can install other things. The problem is that my BIOS doesn't support boot from USB (can't make liveUSB) and booting from CD doesn't work too (I burned a CD from .iso file). Is there a way to do it from normal boot? How?

PS. I did installed my Ubuntu via Wubi, but every time i boot i press "e" and change ro to re (It's exhausting but you can live with it)

Comment: I meant ro to rw

Comment: Are you sure that your issue depends on your installation size? It could be a duplicate of [Ubuntu 14.04 not booting after error message. /tmp could not be mounted](http://askubuntu.com/questions/453411/ubuntu-14-04-not-booting-after-error-message-tmp-could-not-be-mounted)

Comment: You mean ro to rw?

Comment: I just said that i have to change ro to rw when i boot my computer. My problem is that i don't have enough space on my partition.

Comment: I was not sure if you meant that an error message of ro/rw issue said that you had not enough space.

Can you check the output of `df -h` ?  Do you need space at mounting point / (line beginning with /dev/loop0) or mounting point /host (line beginning with /dev/sd..) ? You need the first one for system files, the second one you can use for other files like pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Boot a Live CD (You're better using a Live CD, Wubi is buggy and may just mess up everything.) and start GParted.
Now, just simply expand the partition (if the HDD is full, shrink other partitions to get more free space.)

Comment: everything would be cool, except the fact that my BIOS doesn't want to boot from Ubuntu CD. I don't know why, but it just doesn't.

Comment: Live USB. Or PLoP Boot Manager and then selecting the DVD/CD/whatevar.

Comment: Is there another way than instaling a custom boot menager?