# Formatting the loopback device?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, wubi, swap, loop-device

I'm very new to Ubuntu, I used the Windows installer to install it aside with Windows 7. I chose the same partition as it has enough space. I got this message when the computer rebooted and I'm afraid if I press continue, any data would be lost. I don't actually know much about the "Loopback" and "swap".

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: By "Windows installer", you mean `wubi.exe`?

Comment: Which Ubuntu version and which Wubi version do you use ? It looks like Ubuntu 14.04.2 or 14.04.3 and the Wubi version from iso file. Wubi formats a loopback device (**C:\ubuntu\disks\root.disk**) by default.
The real question is "Why you have to confirm a default value to continue?". The answer is that this Wubi version is unmaintained. If you continue you will get [this issue](http://askubuntu.com/q/453411/386067).
From my experience it is better to avoid Wubi or to use a Community supported version from [here](http://bit.ly/1O1AJLz).

Answer (score 2):

What should I do ?
You should STOP !

Installing Ubuntu via `wubi` is not recommended.
Download the [Ubuntu desktop](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) installation image.
Burn this ISO file to a DVD or create an USB media.
Boot from the installation media and install Ubuntu.

Read about all details in the [Ubuntu installation guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu).

To create an USB media from within Windows properly,
open **command prompt as administrator** and execute:

```
diskpart
list disk  
select disk *  
clean  
create partition primary  
active  
format fs=fat32 (quick)  
assign letter=**
```

Note : `*` = number of the USB drive | `**` = select a free drive letter
Mount the Ubuntu ISO file and copy all the content to the USB drive.