# Dowgrade Upgrade WUBI Ubuntu Precise 12.1 replacing only PPA

Tags: 12.04, wubi, ppa

Life is matter of Risk but should be well calculated. I have been using Xubutu 12.04 under `wubi` for a While on Ideapad S12 but It was quite uneasy to work with this buggy solution. I did get a try with Mint equivalent of `wubi` running on Mint 14 KDE  DVD on Lenovo X61. It still lacks a lot because the ppa are empty since Quantal 12.1 is no more supported.

As Precise will die in April 2017, I am wondering what to do next:

1. I keep it as it is forget any update and install every program with deb or script
2. I try to replace the quantal PPA with the precise one. Not really a downgrade but software Center should work afterwards.
3. Since from what I have read an upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04 with `wubi` is a headache possibly it will be the same with MINT 14 going to 17. However what about changing only the PPA.

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: @Zanna: Italian English is my guess...  Edited to clarify.  Next time, just ping me in chat.  :)

Comment: Some questions: Do you want to use internet with your system? If not, keep it as it is and never connect it with internet again. Do you know the [Wubi upgrade issue](http://askubuntu.com/questions/453411/ubuntu-14-04-not-booting-after-error-message-tmp-could-not-be-mounted)? Do you read [Wubi info](http://askubuntu.com/tags/wubi/info)?

Answer (score 1):

Another proposition on top of your 3 possibilities as `wubi` is a dead end street.

4. just bite the bullet now and:

   - Take a full back-up of your data
   - flash your BIOS (to get rid of the firmware bug)
   - Wipe your virus-ridden Windows and install 16.04 [as per here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

That way:

- you will have a clean, working system
- you will have future-proofness
- you will have Long Term Support
- you can always install Wine Is Not an Emulator ([wine](https://www.winehq.org/)) for those applications that really need Windows and are not available on Ubuntu (I have none, but some people do)

Answer (score 0):

Wubi does not work with Windows 8 and Windows 10 in UEFI mode, which is how Windows is delivered, when pre-installed. So Wubi is no longer supported and no longer developed by Ubuntu. It is a dead-end street. See this link,

[Ubuntu Forums Staff recommendations on WUBI](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2229766)

I suggest that you try a light-weight Ubuntu flavour, for example Lubuntu, and if it works live, install it alongside Windows, 'dual boot'. See this link and links from it,

[Try Ubuntu (Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, ...) before installing it](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389)

Answer (score 0):

I know that Wubi is a dead end unfortunately
However is quite safe environement against virus
Unfortunately flashing the BIOS do not get rid of new firmware virus rootkit
I have already try and I have read a lot on this virus type.
You need to remove the bios chip but also it remain to the Hardisk firmware maybe also on the ethernet card and so and so.
My computer will be already in the basket I i did find this solution to use Wubi and Linux.
I can sent you a bibliography about firmware virus. Actually I have boot a new PC but It had been lost in the mail for mow because of error ebay shipping address.
Actually only HP Elibook come with bios protection usih Biossphere. However I need to find a way to sent my data on the infest Lenovo to the new one,
I am planning to use dropbox and cloud to pas my data. Actually virus firmware need hardware contact as USB key, removeable hard disk.

For this I will use wubi as much as I can on my dead walking Lenovo...
I have try to use PPA of Precise 12.01 but it do not work very well.
I try to add PPA from old Ubuntu repertory I did not work either
Actually I believe the only way to do it is to create a DVD of the PPA but It will take a bunch of DVVD since the PPA is more than 50GB.
From this experience I undesrtstand never use a Linux distribution for less than 5 years because It is really a headeache when they remove the PPA from the cloud.